# Nested for-loop issue

Tags: java

This piece of code is returning an issue in Netbeans Java

```
public static void main(String str[]) throws Exception {
    NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();

    for (int i = 0; i &lt; devices.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " :" + devices[i].name + "(" + devices[i].description + ")");
        System.out.println("    data link:" + devices[i].datalink_name + "(" + devices[i].datalink_description + ")");
        System.out.print("    MAC address:");            
        for (byte b : devices[i].mac_address) {                 
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b &amp; 0xff) + ":");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (NetworkInterfaceAddress a : devices[i].addresses) {
            System.out.println("    address:" + a.address + " " + a.subnet + " " + a.broadcast);
        }
    }

    JpcapCaptor jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[1], 2000, true, 20);    
    jpcap.loopPacket(-1, new packet_cap());
}
```

Two lines of code are listed as 'not a statement' and expected ) and } .

```
for (int i = 0; i &lt; devices.length; i++)
```

and

```
System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b &amp; 0xff) + ":");
```

I'm sure these issues are related.

Comment: `&lt;` and `&amp;` may be the issue.

Comment: Should &lt; be < in for statement or did SOF converted it ?

Comment: Change &lt; with < , you are not handling with xml

Comment: Oh I just edited the post to fix &lt; and &amp;, I thought they were somehow copy paste errors (HTML/XML encoded). I didn't think those could seriously be overlooked as the source of the bugs :)

Comment: But they are in all probability the source of the bugs! 
The errors are saying there are syntax problems and after removing those 2 characters, I don't think there are any syntactic errors.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I reverted your edit as it most likely was the sources of the problems.

Comment: @jpw Yes, it seems to be the case. I suppose he did indeed copy/paste it from an HTML / XML source and posted his question here when it would not compile. Thanks for undoing that edit. edit; you left one `&` in there, the `Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff)` in his large code block was also encoded in the original question.

Comment: @jpw actually you didn't, you rolled back your own revision it seems. :p I fixed it, and kept your tag changes. Edit: Whops, looks like too many people were trying to do this at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have copied and pasted from HTML.

`for (int i = 0; i &lt; devices.length; i++)`

the `&lt`  should be `<`.

Also `System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b &amp; 0xff) + ":");`

`&amp;`  should be `&`.

Comment: I learn everyday - Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**`&lt;`** and **`&amp`** are not valid keywords or identifier in Java. These are XML encoded operators. E.g. **`&lt;`** means `<`; I assume you copied the sourcecode from a website.